# How to stick label names with their background colors in a real time chart

Tags: javascript, graph, label, bar-chart

I'm just a guy who was trying to make a bar chart that updates dynamically every amount of seconds. I found that JS is a good option (I couldn't figure out how to do it with Excel).

After doing some research on JS and finally making it dynamic and sorting by highest to the lowest value, I found some problems that I hope you could help me with:

1. I want the background colors to stick to the label names (Dog, cow, pig, etc). Now it's sticking to the values sorted as you can see.
2. I can't find where to put the setInterval to update the values and positions (I've been trying to put it in different parts of the code, but I can't find the right place). Now it's making the whole chart every 3 seconds (I just want to update values and positions). I think by doing this it will show the transition of values smoother.

[Link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wc9g3Ltd/)

```
const CHART = document.getElementById("chart");

Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 1000;

Chart.plugins.register({
  beforeUpdate: function(chart) {
if (chart.options.sort) {
  let dataArray = chart.data.datasets[0].data.slice();
  let dataIndexes = dataArray.map((d, i) => i);
  dataIndexes.sort((a, b) => {
    return dataArray[a] - dataArray[b];
  });

  // sort data array as well
  dataArray.sort((a, b) => b - a);

  // At this point dataIndexes is sorted by value of the data, so we know how the indexes map to each other
  let meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
  let newMeta = [];
  let labels = chart.data.labels;
  let newLabels = [];


  meta.data.forEach((a, i) => {
    newMeta[dataIndexes[i]] = a;
    newLabels[dataIndexes[i]] = chart.data.labels[i];
  });

  meta.data = newMeta;
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = dataArray;
  chart.data.labels = newLabels;
    }
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
let barChart = new Chart(CHART,  {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
labels: ['Chicken', 'Tuna', 'Cow', 'Pig', 'Dog', 'Mermaid'],
datasets: [{
  label: "Animals (and Mermaid)",
  //How to stick this background colors to each label
  backgroundColor: [
    "#467261",
    "#556e69",
    "#555341",
    "#4e6577",
    "#537061",
    "#44656e"
  ],

  data: [Math.random()*1000, Math.random()*1000, Math.random()*1000, Math.random()*1000, Math.random()*1000, Math.random()*1000]

}]
  },
  options: {
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true
    }
  }],
  yAxes: [{
    barThickness: 30
  }]

}
  }

});

    barChart.options.sort = true;
  barChart.update();
  },3000);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create your data in a single array and sort it by the random value for each interval and sort it all together.

```
var adata = [
    ["Chicken", "red", Math.random()*1000],
    ["Tuna",    "#556e69", Math.random()*1000],
    ["Cow",     "#555341", Math.random()*1000],
    ["Pig",     "#4e6577", Math.random()*1000],
    ["Dog",     "#537061", Math.random()*1000],
    ["Mermaid", "#44656e", Math.random()*1000],
];
adata.sort(function(a, b) {return b[2] - a[2];});
```

You then have to remove all the sorting functions done in beforeUpdate.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2dyfa0xj/